# How do I use the "Handles" clause from Visual Basic .NET with a DLL written using C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, interop

In a Visual Basic .NET application, is there a way to use `Handles` on an object referenced in a DLL written in C#? Compiling the code gives me the error:

> 'Handles' in modules must specify a
>   'WithEvents' variable qualified with a
>   single identifier.

I'm writing the Visual Basic .NET application, but I do have the source code of the C# library available.

My current code looks something like this:

```
WithEvents Friend Module As ModuleNamespace.Module
Sub EventHandler() Handles Module.Events.Event1
    Console.WriteLine("Event1 fired.")
End Sub
```

Replacing `Module`, `ModuleNamespace`, and `Event1` with the actual names.

Answer (score 2):

You need a module level variable to contain the object instance. Air code:

```
 Private WithEvents mMyObject As CSharpObject

 Private Sub MyEvent(...) Handles mMyObject.SomeEvent
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have an object instance handy for the events to be bound to. Can you try using AddHandler instead of the Handles keyword?

For example:

```
Private Sub BindEvents(ByVal someObject AS ClassInLibrary)

  AddHandler someObject.EventName, AddressOf Foo

End Sub

Private Sub Foo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using AddHandler now, but I was just wondering if there was a more efficient/cleaner way to accomplish the same goal, as runtime binding isn't necessary for my application.

Comment: Unless you've got a module level variable like MarkJ suggests you'll have to call AddHandler yourself. When you use WithEvents and Handles the compiler actually emits a property and calls AddHandler itself in the setter.